# MVC Scaffolding with Custom T4 Templates in VS 2012 Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, t4

Just getting started with customizing the generated MVC Controller / Views.

Following Steven Sanderson's post:
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/04/06/mvcscaffolding-overriding-the-t4-templates/

I used the Package Manager Console to generate 3 custom templates in my VS 2012 MVC4 project

```
PM>Scaffold CustomTemplate View Create

PM>Scaffold CustomTemplate View Edit

PM>Scaffold CustomTemplate View _CreateOrEdit
```

which creates a the files in:
CodeTemplates\Scaffolders\MvcScaffolding.RazorView
_CreateOrEdit.cs.t4  Create.cs.t4  Edit.cs.t4

But, when I  "Add Controller" and choose the template
Mvc Controller with read/write actions and views using Entity Framework

***The new templates are NOT being used ???***

I was able to modify the  create.tt edit.tt templates with notepad in 
the VS 2012 folder and then generate with the changes in my project.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpress\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 4\CodeTemplates\AddView\CSHTML

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks, LA Guy

Comment: Hi, downloaded Nuget Package: MvcCodeTemplatesCSharp which created CodeTemplates\AddController\Controller.tt and \AddView\Create.tt Edit.tt etc. and YES, modifying these inline templates does work.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a `CodeTemplates\AddView\CSHTML` folder inside your solution and put your templates there (or `CodeTemplates\AddController` for a controller template). It worked for me in VS2012. These can be checked into source control and everyone can share them. The ones in your VS install directory are a bit harder to share.